# How to trigger "IsRemoteSession" or "IsSoftwareRendering" in UserControl style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

We are developing usercontrols with .NET 4 - WPF.
We have a lot of customers who are running our application in a remote session (e.g. Terminal-Server, Citriy, etc.).

Many of the performance issues are already solved. At the moment I'm searching for a way to disable animations in styles and controltemplates depending on the condition of `IsRemoteSession` and/or `IsSoftwareRendering`. I will do that without writing a line of code.

I'm pretty sure that I read a blog article some months ago in which it described a way to do that using a trigger in xaml, but I can't find it anymore.

Anyone have any hints....?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is by putting the animations inside the triggers. The code would look something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type WhateverYourTypeIs}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- Here I assume your whatever holds your IsRemoteSession property is your DataContext -->
        <!-- Otherwise, change your binding -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsRemoteSession}"
                     Value="False">
            <!-- Here you use Setters to add your animations -->
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about this way, but then i need in every control in the datacontext some dp which calculates the is remote session state. I'm pretty sure, that there is an more easy way....

Comment: @Carsten: You don't need a dependency property, use a normal CLR property somewhere you can bind to and have the class implement `INotifyPropertyChange` like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx). This will then notify anything bound to your property of any changes to its value.